# Shared Drive (Dual Boot): Auto-mounting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, fstab

Currently dual-booting Win10/Ubuntu and I'm wanting to auto-mount a shared NTFS drive that I created earlier today. I watched some video tutorial on YouTube explaining how to get the drive details and edit your fstab file, which I've done: [Pastebin: Fstab file](http://pastebin.com/2FLh3pkL).

I've also done this without the UUID and using /dev/sda10 instead but no luck, I still get an "Error while mounting" on boot. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how about `mount /dev/sda10 /mnt`, keep the argument minimum to test.

Comment: Replacing that last line of the fstab?

Comment: no just go into terminal and mount it manually via that command. if the filesystem is wrong or the module is not loaded, it will throw you some errors.

Comment: Try removing quotes from UUID entry. `UUID=XXXXXXXXXXX   /media/kuomi/SHARE ntfs defaults,nls=utf8,umask=000,uid=1000,windows_names 0 0` You did create the mount point /mediai/kuomi/SHARE? Also before rebooting but after editing fstab run this: `sudo mount -a` if no errors they you know it is correct.

Comment: I did try removing the quotes but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Even dual booting, its unlikely that you have 10 partitions on sda, so /dev/sda10 is probably incorrect. (Because of primary/secondary partitions there could be as little as 7, but my point remains.) I would run

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
```

to try and identify for sure what partition your Windows drive is on. It should have type NTFS.

Another option if you have a full desktop installed, would be to browse to the drive using the file manager. This will automatically mount it under `/media/$yourusername`. You can then use the `df` command to see what partition it mounted and use that in your fstab instead of /dev/sda10

Comment: After double checking, it is definitely sda10. I have ten partitions on sda, about 5x Win ones, this SHARE partition, 3 ubuntu and a lenovo partition.

Comment: I also noticed under your pastebin fstab that your fs type is fuseblk. This is what the kernel reports for a mounted NTFS partition, but you should try type ntfs in your fstab. Last I knew ubuntu still uses [NTFS-3G](http://www.tuxera.com/community/open-source-ntfs-3g/)